# Piranha-CMS How do you get the Post to display on the Page?

Tags: piranha-cms

I need to get the posts to display on one of my pages...

How to I do this? Can I create the link via the database? I would prefer this if possible as I'm way better at sql than C#

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's are two **regions** you can add to your page type, `Posts` & `Post Models`. The first only loads the general information while the second loads the entire post models including all extensions.

Then in your page you get to select which post type, the number of posts, included related entities & sort order for the posts.

You can read about the included standard regions here:
http://piranhacms.org/docs/pages/regions

Regards

/Håkan